# Evaluating $\lim_{x\to\infty} x^{7/2} \left[\sqrt{x+1}+\sqrt{x-1}-2\sqrt{x}\left(1-\frac1{8x^2}\right)\right] $

Tags: calculus, limits

How would I go about doing this limit?
$$\lim_{x\to\infty} x^{7/2} \left[\sqrt{x+1}+\sqrt{x-1}-2\sqrt{x}\left(1-\frac1{8x^2}\right)\right] $$

I have tried manipulating it into various forms and using L'Hôpital's rule to no avail. Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange.  $\sqrt{1+\dfrac1x}=1+\dfrac1{2x}-\dfrac1{8x^2}+\dfrac1{16x^3}-\dfrac5{128x^4}+O\left(\left(\dfrac1x\right)^5\right)$

Answer (score 3):

Here's an idea to get you started.

$$\lim_{x\to\infty} x^{7/2} \left[\sqrt{x+1}+\sqrt{x-1}-2\sqrt{x}\left(1-\frac1{8x^2}\right)\right] $$

$$=\lim_{x\to\infty} x^{4} \left[\sqrt{1+\frac1x}+\sqrt{1-\frac1x}-2\left(1-\frac1{8x^2}\right)\right]. $$

Now use the [binomial series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_series)
$\sqrt{1+\dfrac1x}=1+\dfrac1{2x}-\dfrac1{8x^2}+\dfrac1{16x^3}-\dfrac5{128x^4}+O\left(\left(\dfrac1x\right)^5\right)$

and an analogous one for $\sqrt{1-\dfrac1x}.\;$  Can you take it from here?

Comment: Thanks, I see what to do now.

Answer (score 0):

Rationalizing by introducing [conjugates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conjugate_(square_roots)) usually works for limits like this. Label each term in the limand by

$$\lim_{x\to\infty}x^{7/2}\left(\underbrace{\sqrt{x+1}}_a + \underbrace{\sqrt{x-1}}_b - \underbrace{2\sqrt x}_c + \underbrace{\frac1{4x^{3/2}}}_d\right)$$

One way to rewrite the limand is to do

$$\begin{align}
a+b-c+d &= \frac{(a+b-c+d)(a-b+c+d)}{a-b+c+d} \\[1ex]
&= \frac{a^2-b^2-c^2+d^2+2(ad+bc)}{a-b+c+d}
\end{align}$$

You're free to use another permutation of signs, of course; I just happened to land on this one and found it left the fewest non-radical terms across the handful of sequences I tried.

In full, the limand simplifies to

$$\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{x^{7/2}\left(2 - 4x + \frac1{16x^3} + \frac12\sqrt{\frac1{x^2}+\frac1{x^3}} + 4\sqrt{x^2-x}\right)}{\sqrt{x+1}-\sqrt{x-1}+2\sqrt x + \frac1{4x^{3/2}}}$$

From the denominator, pull out a factor of $\sqrt x$ and simplify $\frac{x^{7/2}}{\sqrt x}=x^3$ to rebrand this as

$$\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{x^3\left(2 - 4x + \frac1{16x^3} + \frac12\sqrt{\frac1{x^2}+\frac1{x^3}} + 4\sqrt{x^2-x}\right)}{\sqrt{1+\frac1x}-\sqrt{1-\frac1x}+2+\frac1{4x^{5/2}}}$$

Split the limit over the quotient, and notice that the denominator approaches

$$\lim_{x\to\infty}\left(\sqrt{1+\frac1x}-\sqrt{1-\frac1x}+2+\frac1{4x^{5/2}}\right) = 1-1+2+0 = 2$$

so that the original limit is equal to

$$\frac12 \lim_{x\to\infty} x^3\left(2 - 4x + \frac1{16x^3} + \frac12\sqrt{\frac1{x^2}+\frac1{x^3}} + 4\sqrt{x^2-x}\right)$$

or upon distributing $x^3$ and subsequently extracting the constant term and scalar factors,

$$\frac1{32} + \lim_{x\to\infty} \left(x^3 - 2x^4 + \frac14\sqrt{x^4+x^3} + 2\sqrt{x^8-x^7}\right)$$

You can try employing the same "trick" for the remaining limit.

---

I'll omit some of the details, but I managed to rewrite the previous limit as

$$\frac1{64} - \frac14 \lim_{x\to\infty} \left(x^2-\sqrt{x^4-x^2}\right)$$

and this subsequent limit as

$$\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{x^2}{x^2+\sqrt{x^4-x^2}} = \lim_{x\to\infty}\frac1{1+\sqrt{1-\frac1{x^2}}}$$

Then the ultimate result would be

$$\frac1{32} + \frac1{64} - \frac14\cdot\frac12 = -\frac5{64}$$

Answer (score 0):

By Taylor's series

$f(x+h)
=f(x)+hf'(x)+h^2f''(x)/2+h^3f'''(x)/6
+h^4f''''(x)/24+h^5f^{(5)}(x)/120+O(h^6)$

so

$f(x+h)-2f(x)+f(x-h)
=h^2f''(x)+h^4f''''(x)/12+O(h^6)
$.

Letting
$f(x)
=\sqrt{x}
$,
since
$f'(x)
=\frac12 x^{-1/2},
f''(x)
=-\frac14 x^{-3/2},
f'''(x)
=\frac38 x^{-5/2},
f''''(x)
=-\frac{15}{16} x^{-7/2},
$

$\sqrt{1+\frac1{x}}-2+\sqrt{1-\frac1{x}}
= -\frac1{4x^2}-\frac{15}{16*12x^4}+O(x^{-6})
= -\frac1{4x^2}-\frac{5}{64x^4}+O(x^{-6})
$.

Therefore,
using J. W. Tanner's expression,

$\begin{array}\\
x^{4} \left[\sqrt{1+\frac1x}+\sqrt{1-\frac1x}-2\left(1-\frac1{8x^2}\right)\right]
&=x^{4} \left[\sqrt{1+\frac1x}+\sqrt{1-\frac1x}-2+\frac1{4x^2}\right]\\
&=x^{4} \left[-\frac1{4x^2}-\frac{5}{64x^4}+O(x^{-6})+\frac1{4x^2}\right]\\
&=-\frac{5}{64}+O(x^{-2})\\
\end{array}
$